# How to add a JButton to a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I tried to add a button to the `JFrame`, but it won't appear for some reason. How do I make it appear?

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GraficoconArreglo extends javax.swing.JFrame {
 JPanel pan = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
 JLabel []lab = new JLabel[6];
 JTextField []text = new JTextField[6];
 Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.pink,1);
 JButton b = new JButton("Calculate");

public GraficoconArreglo() {
    initComponents();
    pan.setLayout(null);
    pan.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    for(int i=0; i<lab.length ;i++){
        lab[i] = new JLabel();
        text[i] = new JTextField();

        lab[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(15,(i+1)*40, 60, 25));
        lab[i].setText("Data " + (i+1));
        lab[i].setBorder(border);
        text[i].setBounds(new Rectangle(100,(i+1)*40, 60, 25));

        pan.add(lab[i],null);
        pan.add(text[i],null);

        setSize(200,330);
        setTitle("Arrays in forums.");

        add(b);
        b.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    }        
}
```

Comment: Never use a null layout.  Never try to call `setBounds` directly.  It'll never work.  Your button is probably not appearing because it is outside of the bounds.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) ..

Comment: .. along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating only one button and adding it to 6 different places. Therefore, you only would see it on the last place you added.

Answer (score -2):

You should add the button to the contentPane, not the JFrame. A working code for this, provided from SwingDesigner from Eclipse Marketplace would be:

```
public class Window extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Window frame = new Window();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Window() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(170, 110, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
}
```

}

Comment: (1-) Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. `You should add the button to the contentPane, not the JFrame.` - you can add the button to the frame. The add() method of the frame will forward the component to the content pane of the frame. There is no need to specifically set the content pane to a panel, since the default content pane already is a JPanel.